# How to convert self-hosted WCF service to IIS 7

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis

I currently have a self-hosted WCF service running in a Windows service. I have been asked to host the WCF service in IIS 7. It seems that all of the MSDN suggestion require me to implement a wrapper class for the service instead of loading the service dll directly via a configuration file. I have already read the links [Why/how to migrate self-hosted WCF service to IIS7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391255/why-how-to-migrate-self-hosted-wcf-service-to-iis7) and [WCF Service. Can't host in IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935760/wcf-service-cant-host-in-iis7?rq=1). Has anybody done this before? If so, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: So, what's your exact problem? What questions were not answered by those links?

Comment: That's the problem - you haven't said what your question is.

Comment: I am looking for a "how to" reference that will show me step by step the sequence of exposing WCF service dlls in IIS 7. I had some success with creating a new project in VS 2010 of type "WCF Service Application", which references the dlls in question. But this method created a new wrapper around the existing services. Is there a way to expose the dlls without creating a new project?

Comment: What do you mean, "wrapper"? Are you referring to the .svc file? All you need to do is create a .svc file pointing to the service, then set the configuration accordingly.

Comment: Step 1: Create .NET Framework 4 WCF Service Application Step 2: Add Reference to the WCF DLLs. Step 3: Right click on Service1.scv (auto-generated) and select "View Markup" Should look like this: `code`<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="WcfService4.Service1" CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs" %>`code`. Step 4: replace "...Service1" with the services from the DLLs.  Remove the tag  CodeBehind="Service1.svc.cs". Step 5: Right click on solution, Publish to yoursever/yourpage. Enable "Mark as IIS...". Step 7: open yourserver/yourpage/Service1.scv

Comment: Excellent, and _then_ what happens? Does it fail? If it fails, then _how_, ***precisely*** does it fail?